# LZ4 file compression in Java

Tags: java, compression, lz4

What is the best way to feed a huge CSV file to LZ4 compression API? The following isn't optimal for very large files.

```
byte[] data = file.getBytes();
```

Comment: Based on http://jpountz.github.io/lz4-java/1.2.0/docs/net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4FastDecompressor.html, I don’t think you can.  Do you absolutely need LZ4 compression?  I would consider [gzip compression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html).

Comment: gzip is way slower for what I need - it gives me around 50-75 MB/s compression speed. There must be be a way to use inputstream with lz4 ?

Comment: You would have to look into how many bytes constitute a single LZ4 compressable unit, and process that many at a time from the InputStream… assuming LZ4 even has such a concept.

Comment: Changed my comment to an actual answer.

Comment: For anyone finding this in the future: Apache commons compress supports streaming into an LZ4 compressor now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/flanglet/kanzi. The block compressor takes an InputStream and splits it into blocks (you specify the size in the command line).

From the Wiki, you can do something like this:

java -cp kanzi.jar kanzi.app.BlockCompressor --input=myFile.csv --output=myFile.knz --overwrite --block=8M --transform=lz --entropy=none